# Настроить PHP парсер DiDOM

Tags: php, html, css, парсер

Изучаю написание парсера контента, остановился на библиотеке DiDOM.

Получается спарсить нужную информацию с одной страницы:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use DiDom\Document;

$document = new Document('https://site.ru/catalog/tovar/', true);

//Находим заголовок 
$main_heading = $document->find('.product-title h1')[0];
echo $main_heading->html();

//Находим цену
$price = $document->find('.item_current_price')[0];
$price->text();

//Находим фото
$foto = $document->find('.bx_bigimages_imgcontainer img')[0];
```

С одной страницой в целом все понятно. Но, никак **не могу понять логику обхода и получения контента с большого количества страниц**. Как это в принципе делается?

Парсер должен находить дочерние страницы по ссылкам в каталоге товаров (*к примеру*), или получать ссылки их XML карты сайта, или еще каким то образом выгружать список ссылок и потом идти по ним, находя там заданную информацию?

Просьба натолкнуть на мысль, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то раз мне нужно было парсит IP для мониторинга игровых серверов. Там ссылки выглядели так:

```
site.ru/page?page=1 - Тут 50 серверов
site.ru/page?page=2 - Тут 50 серверов
site.ru/page?page=3 - Тут 50 серверов
```

Я сделал просто цикл for:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

 $url = "site.ru/page?page=$i";

 #Тут идет код парсинга

}
```

Где 10 это количество страниц.

Comment: Спасибо, принял к сведению! А можете озвучить какие-либо другие варианты? Интересно, как еще можно подойти к решению вопроса

Comment: @Amsterdam честно говоря нет, так как с парсингом я один раз имел дело и использовал вариант который я уже озвучивал. Посмотрите видео материала по парсингу сайтов разными библиотеками. Что не будь да найдёте.

Comment: ищу, читаю, но пока альтернативных вариантов не выделил. Спасибо за отклик!

Comment: спасибо еще раз за идею с циклом, на основе вашего примера удалось создать свой! Еще хотел поинтересоваться, как настроить работу php парсера через прокси? Тоже пока не могу понять основу этого

Comment: @Amsterdam К сожалению с прокси я не знаком, сам только учусь, извиняйте)

Answer (score 1):

В итоге получился такой вариант (минимальный основополагающий код, который можно и нужно модернизировать)

```
<?php

// Здесь нужно подключить API своей системы, если файл внешний

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use DiDom\Document;

//Получаем каталог с товарами
$document = new Document('http://site.ru/catalog/', true);

//Находим ссылку по которой будем переходить на товар
$links = $document->find('a.startshop-name');

//Создаем цикл
foreach ($links as $key => $value) 
  { 

    //Получаем и проходимся в цикле по всем url товаров, что идет после site.ru/catalog
    $dodo = $value->getAttribute('href');

    //Подставляем массив ссылок для перебора
    $massa = "http://site.ru/$dodo";

    $document = new Document($massa, true);

    //Находим H1 на страницах
    $main_heading = $document->find('h1')[0];

    //Находим фото
    $foto = $document->find('#slider_images a::attr(href)')[0];

    // Здесь создаем новый ресурс через API вашей системы с поставлением полученных данных
```